# asp.net webbrowser file download

Tags: c#, file, download, browser, stream

I have a webbrowser in my windows form application. I navigate a page and after document completed i click "download" button with javascript. cleary ;

```
 wb.Document.GetElementById("btnDownload").InvokeMember("click");
```

then save file dialog shows up. But I need to get this file as stream.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to get this done by extracting url address of the file from a page and use WebClient to download file [WebClient.DownloadFile Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)